# Вопрос связанный с сетями.

Tags: сеть

Добрый день! Всех с праздником!
Есть вопрос. Написал "tcp-чат". В локальной сети всё работает-можно обмениваться сообщениями. Чат перестает работать(клиенты не коннектятся к серверу) если приложение клиента и сервера стоят на компах, которые находятся в разных сетях. Например, если человек с приложением-сервер живет в Москве, а другой с приложением-клиент в С.Петербурге, то клиент не соединяется с сервером... Читал про это дело... Там говорят есть два ip:
1)ip хоста.
2)ip который хост выдает нам.
Когда общаешься в локалке-хост не задействован и нет проблем с ip. А как быть если нужно слать через хост? Читал я про NAT. Что-то не понял момента про то как хост определяет что этот пакет данных адресован именно вот "ему", а другой пакет адресован "тому". Можете с 0 на простом языке обьяснить как устроено это дело с подменой ip адреса?
Спасиюо)

Answer (score 3):

Не уверен, что ваше непонимание напрямую связано именно с NAT. Проброс портов, это и есть тот самый NAT. Представим, что у вас клиент-серверная архитектура чата. При этом сервер находится за маршрутизатором (т.е. маршрутизатор, да, имеет глобальный IP). В то же время "сервер находится за маршрутизатором" значит, что этот, написанный вами сервер, установлен на одном из компьютеров, имеющих доступ к интернет посредством маршрутизатора. Таким образом появляется второй IP - внутренний, который неизвестен (по ряду причин) глобальному интернет-пространству.

Схема проста:

1. Ваш сервер на локальном компьютере с внутренним IP слушает на порту, например, 2000
2. Все соединения к вашему серверу внутри этой сети доходят и ничем практически не ораничены
3. Ваш клиент, на другом локальном компьютере зная IP и порт на сервере, выполняет подключение, и все работает

Если же стало так, что клиент находится за пределами внутренней сети, но ему очень хочется добраться до сервера, вы будете использовать уже внешний адрес, который виден всем в интернете (по большей части). Но, поскольку, в общем случае обратившись по внешнему IP и порту 2000 вы никакого соединения не получите, т.к. маршрутизатор попросту не знает что с ним делать, вам и необходим проброс портов. Что в итоге выльется в следующую картину:

1. Клиент (не важно где он, лишь бы доступ был к всемирной паутине), инициирует соединение по внешнему IP и порту 2000
2. Маршрутизатор, имеющий настройки NAT по перебросу пакетов с внешнего IP и порта 2000 на внутренний IP, компьютера, где стоит ваш сервер. Будем полагать, что порт не изменяется.
3. Сервер принимает соединение, отправляя подтверждение обратно, которое в общем случае проходит обратный путь, описанному в п.2.
4. Клиент удачно установил соединение

Работая на высоком уровне абстракции, вам не нужно заботиться о NAT. Вы разработали программу, которая может подключаться к серверу где угодно, лишь бы сервер был доступен.

Comment: Т.е. нужны маршрутизаторы(для сервера и клиента) которые перебрасывают пакеты с внешних адресов на внутренние...
А как так? Допустим у меня есть клиент ICQ, сервер пока опустим...
Как информация, посланная сервером доходит до клиентра при connection? Присутствует переброс пакетов клиента? Но я ничего настраивал на маршрутизаторе... А можно как-то программно сказать маршрутизатору, чтобы он перебрасывал пакеты на тот или иной ip?
Можете дать ссылку на хороший сайт, сататью, книжку по этой теме.

Answer (score 1):

**Нужен статический ip и проброс портов.**

Comment: У меня статический IP, только существует как бы по 2 ip: ip локальной сети(в которой собственно я есть) и ip хоста через который я отправляю запросы на другие сервера... Проброс портов -это переназначение портов? А это причем тут?
При отправке запроса на другой сервер, как я понял, я прошу хост запросить эти данные... Хост запрашивает и передает эти данные мне... Каким образом хост знает, что именно я запросил ту или иную информацию я не знаю. Какая-то загадка для меня. Как он это делает??? 
Так вот, когда я подсоединяюсь к серверу, который далеко, я нахожу его по ip, по ip его хоста...

Comment: Но вот в чем дело, хост мне не нужен. А как бэ я к нему хочу подключится... Мне нужно как бы не видеть этот хост... Как подключиться к такому серверу???? Неужели никто не знает? HEELP!